# Merge df in two keys, just working for one key

Tags: python, pandas, merge

so I've two df, They need to be merged in two keys `Channel and Week`. When attempting the merging it returns NaN values for all rows in Column Contacts_F..

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'week' : ['01', '02', '45'] ,
                    'Channel' : ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
                    'level' : ['1degre','2degre','3degre']  })
df.dtypes
out[131]:
week               object
Channel            object
level              object



reff_table = pd.DataFrame({ 'week' : ['01', '02', '45'] ,
                            'Channel' : ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
                            'Contacts_F' : ['0.11','0.546','0.06458']  })
reff_table.dtypes
out[132]:
week               object
Channel            object
Contacts_F         float64



print(df.week[:3]), print(reff_table.week[:3])

0    00
1    00
2    00
Name: week, dtype: object
0    103
1    102
2    101
Name: week, dtype: object
(None, None)
```

My attempts:

It is returning **NaN** values for all rows in column= **Contacts_F**

/.

```
df = pd.merge(df, reff_table [["Channel", "week" , "Contacts_F"]],on=['Channel','week'], how='left')
```

It works if I merge only ON Column=**Channel**, but I need match both columns.

```
df = pd.merge(df, reff_table [["Channel", "week" , "Contacts_F"]],on=['Channel', how='left')
```

Comment: your code works for me, (after fixing it) you need to check the columns, they are probably not of the same dtypes or there is some subtle difference you are missing.

Comment: Does your current code throw any errors?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, It doesnt, it seems it is finding the Column=Channel, but then some reason doesnt find column=week.

What is weird, they are some data type, and identical the some

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I found the Answer.. and posted. kind of silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was.. in the Reff table the numbers was wrong like `41.0 Vs 41`. 
So Pandas was printing and Displaying it as `41`.
I had to go verify it in the actual database, then I saw the problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'week' : ['01', '02', '45'] ,
                    'Channel' : ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
                    'level' : ['1degre','2degre','3degre']  })



reff_table = pd.DataFrame({ 'week' : ['01', '02', '45'] ,
                            'Channel' : ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
                            'Contacts_F' : ['0.11','0.546','0.06458']  })

# This fix the problem
df.week.str.replace('.', '').astype(str)



df = pd.merge(df, reff_table [["Channel", "week" , "Contacts_F"]],on=['Channel','week'], how='left')
```

Comment: I think that `astype()`is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

See below for working example of how to perform merge. Various syntax errors in prompt are corrected.

```py
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame({'week': [1, 2, 45],
                       'Channel': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
                       'level': ['1degre', '2degre', '3degre']})

    reff_table = pd.DataFrame({'week': [1, 2, 45],
                               'Channel': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
                               'Contacts_F': ['0.11', '0.546', '0.06458']})

    pd.merge(df, reff_table, on=['Channel', 'week'], how='left')

    ------

    Out[8]:
        week Channel   level Contacts_F
     0     1      AA  1degre       0.11
     1     2      BB  2degre      0.546
     2    45      CC  3degre    0.06458
```